# Issue with Firebase Console Campaign - Unable to Target iOS Devices

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I am currently facing an issue with the Firebase Console campaign functionality, specifically when attempting to target iOS devices. The console consistently displays 0 potential users, and even after running the campaign, it shows "send 0". Surprisingly, I can successfully send FCM notifications to Android devices.

I use the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js locally and send FCM through registered FCM tokens, I can successfully send notifications to both iOS and Android devices.But why for ios target group it failing in console?